# Autobus add-on is being removed from Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I just received an email from Autobus saying that due to "**Salesforce's complete and long-term failure to fulfill its obligations to us we have to stop our service starting December 1, 2022.**".

That is very unfortunate as we don't really have an alternative add-on (Remora Offsite Backup starts at $75/month).

Does anyone know how to automatically backup Postgres database from Heroku automatically without Autobus help?

Answer (score 0):

For now we have to setup scheduled backups using the Heroku CLI...

```
heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '20:00 America/Sao_Paulo'
```

More details at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups